# How do I send an int over a serial port in c++?

Tags: c++, char, serial-port, int

I am developing a game simulator for Project Cars, I have the code that takes the data from the Shared Memory of PC, but now I have to send it through serial, It must be send to an arduino. I have searched how to do it, but I have no found how to send a Int(that is the data that the API takes from the game) to a serial port.

Here is my code

```
// Used for memory-mapped functionality
#include <windows.h>
#include "sharedmemory.h"

// Used for this example
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//Serial
#include <iostream>
#include "SerialClass.h"
using namespace std;

// Name of the pCars memory mapped file
#define MAP_OBJECT_NAME "$pcars$"

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitle("API F1 Steering Wheel for Project Cars");

    Serial* Puerto = new Serial("COM4");

    // Open the memory-mapped file
    HANDLE fileHandle = OpenFileMapping( PAGE_READONLY, FALSE, MAP_OBJECT_NAME );
    if (fileHandle == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Could not open file mapping object (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the data structure
    const SharedMemory* sharedData = (SharedMemory*)MapViewOfFile( fileHandle, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, sizeof(SharedMemory) );
    if (sharedData == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Could not map view of file (%d).\n", GetLastError() );

        CloseHandle( fileHandle );
        return 1;
    }

    // Ensure we're sync'd to the correct data version
    if ( sharedData->mVersion != SHARED_MEMORY_VERSION )
    {
        printf( "Data version mismatch\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // TEST DISPLAY CODE
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printf( "ESC TO EXIT\n\n", sharedData->mUnfilteredSteering );
    while (true)
    {
        const bool isValidParticipantIndex = sharedData->mViewedParticipantIndex != -1 && sharedData->mViewedParticipantIndex < sharedData->mNumParticipants && sharedData->mViewedParticipantIndex < STORED_PARTICIPANTS_MAX;
        if ( isValidParticipantIndex )
        {
            const ParticipantInfo& viewedParticipantInfo = sharedData->mParticipantInfo[sharedData->mViewedParticipantIndex];
            printf( "mParticipantName: (%s)\n", viewedParticipantInfo.mName );
            printf( "lap Distance = %f \n", viewedParticipantInfo.mCurrentLapDistance );
            printf( "mWorldPosition: (%f,%f,%f)\n", viewedParticipantInfo.mWorldPosition[0], viewedParticipantInfo.mWorldPosition[1], viewedParticipantInfo.mWorldPosition[2] );
        }
        printf( "mGameState: (%d)\n", sharedData->mGameState );
        printf( "mSessionState: (%d)\n", sharedData->mSessionState );
        printf( "mRaceState: (%d)\n", sharedData->mRaceState );
        printf( "mGear: (%d)\n", sharedData-> mGear);
        printf( "mRpm: (%d)\n", sharedData->mRpm);
        printf( "mSpeed: (%d)\n", sharedData->mSpeed);
        system("cls");


        while (Puerto->IsConnected())
        {
            Puerto->WriteData(sharedData->mGear, sizeof(sharedData->mGear)); // Envía al puerto el texto "Luz_ON".
            break;
        }

        if ( _kbhit() && _getch() == 27 ) // check for escape
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Cleanup
    UnmapViewOfFile( sharedData );
    CloseHandle( fileHandle );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where in this code is it not working?

Comment: Also, bytes are usually sent over the wire. An int can be made up of 2 or 4 bytes, so the code will need to convert the int to a byte buffer, then send that over.

Comment: When you can, and you probably can here, prefer `Serial Puerto("COM4");` to `Serial* Puerto = new Serial("COM4");`. Less memory management messiness.

Comment: Be aware that sending multiple bytes without any kind of (message or packet) framing (aka protocol) can easily lead to byte synchronization issues.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is to change this line

```
Puerto->WriteData(sharedData->mGear, sizeof(sharedData->mGear));
```

to this:

```
Puerto->WriteData(&sharedData->mGear, sizeof(sharedData->mGear));
```

Comment: Addendum: I believe Arduino is little endian, but in general [watch out for the byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) when shipping data between computers.

Comment: The `ntoh()` and `hton()` routines are helpful for conversion between host and network ordering.